# Package RCurl fails to connect to URL via sp_execute_external_script

Tags: r, sql-server, sql-server-2017, microsoft-r

I'm trying to do some web scraping with Machine Learning Services using the `RCurl` package for R on SQL 2017. Here's a sample of the `sp_execute_external_script` code I've tried:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script 
    @language = N'R',
    @script = N'library(RCurl)
library(XML)
url <- "http://www.anywebsite.com/"
tables = getURL(url)
tables <- readHTMLTable(tables, header = TRUE, as.data.frame = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = F)
OutputDataSet <- as.data.frame(tables[1])'
WITH RESULT SETS UNDEFINED;
```

I'm getting the following error

> Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 0 A 'R' script error occurred
>   during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT
>   0x80004004. Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 0 An external script
>   error occurred:  Loading required package: bitops Error in function
>   (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :    Failed to connect to
>   www.anywebsite.com port 80: Bad access Calls: source ...
>   getURL -> curlPerform -> .Call ->  -> fun
>
> Error in execution.  Check the output for more information. Error in
>   eval(expr, envir, enclos) :    Error in execution.  Check the output
>   for more information. Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval ->
>   .Call Execution halted

In the `sp_execute_external_script` code, if I change the URL string from "http" to "https", the error is essentially the same, but it references `port 443` instead.
Initial thought is I have a firewall issue. Indeed, if I turn off Windows firewall, `sp_execute_external_script` succeeds.
**So...what exe needs permission?**
I've tried adding exceptions for `sqlservr.exe` (database engine service) and `launchpad.exe` (SQL Server launchpad). Neither attempt has succeeded.

Other Notes:
The `R` code can be run successfully in RStudio, which has an exception in the firewall.
This is a Windows 10 environment with Windows Defender Firewall.

**Update**
As you see below, I've accepted an answer. Here's what it looks like in my Windows 10 environment:
[image: Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security - Outbound Rules]

Comment: Try and make an exception for BxlServer.exe, alternatively RTerm.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the [Windows firewall rule that is automatically installed when Machine Learning Services is added](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/security/firewall-configuration?view=sql-server-2017).

The outbound firewall rule will have a name similar to "Block network access for R local user accounts in SQL Server instance MSSQLSERVER"